# How to get the instance name of an object

Tags: javascript, class, polling, webmethod

I use the below code to write code to query a web method in a specified interval.

now in the this.Poll function I have to do

```
this.tmo = setTimeout(this.strInstanceName + ".Poll()", this.iInterval);
```

instead of

```
this.tmo = setTimeout(this.Poll(), this.iInterval);
```

because IE looses the this pointer after setTimeout

So I have to pass the class it's instance name:

```
    var objPoll = new cPoll("objPoll");
```

How can I get the instance name without passing it as parameter ?

I want to have it outta there !

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Intervall-Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


        function test()
        {
            alert("Test");
            test.tmo = setTimeout(test, 2000);

            test.Clear = function()
            {
                clearTimeout(test.tmo);
            }
        }




        function cPoll(strInstanceName)
        {
            this.strInstanceName = strInstanceName ;
            this.iInterval = 2000;
            this.tmo=null;
            this.cbFunction=null;

            this.Poll = function()
            {
                this.cbFunction();
                this.tmo = setTimeout(this.strInstanceName + ".Poll()", this.iInterval);
            }

            this.Start = function(pCallBackFunction, iIntervalParameter)
            {


                if(this.tmo != null)
                    this.Stop();

                if(iIntervalParameter && iIntervalParameter > 0)
                    this.iInterval=iIntervalParameter;

                this.cbFunction=pCallBackFunction;
                if(this.cbFunction!=null)
                    this.Poll();
                else
                    alert("Invalid or no callback function specified");
            }

            this.Stop = function()
            {
                if(this.tmo != null)
                {
                    clearTimeout(this.tmo);
                    this.tmo=null;
                }
            }
        }


        function CallBackFunction()
        {
            alert("PollCallBack");
        }

        // test();
        // test.Clear();


        var objPoll = new cPoll("objPoll");
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test</h1>

<input type="Button" value="Start polling" onclick="objPoll.Start(CallBackFunction,3000);" />
<input type="Button" value="Stop polling" onclick="objPoll.Stop();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked another question, the answer is here:

[JavaScript: List global variables in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462199/javascript-list-global-variables-in-ie/2462341#2462341)

Iterating through the global variables and check whether it equals "this".

Answer (score 2):

Loose the parenthesis in `this.Poll()`. You call this function right away, not after a time interval. If you loose the brackets, it will pass a function, not a result of it, to `setInterval` and you won't have any issues.

```
setTimeout(this.Poll, this.Interval);
```

Otherwise you call the function right away and nothing holds `this` pointer anymore, and IE just deletes it.

In fixed variant, `this.Poll` will hold pointer to `this` and it won't be deleted.

Comment: Disaster strikes even without braces. Do you use IE != 8 ?

Comment: Do that trick with `self` J-P has posted then. If that doesn't work then your object is being GC'd (or haven't been created) before you call `Start`. So, make sure objPoll is there before you call `Start()` and try to loose `var` before `objPoll = new cPoll("objPoll");`

Comment: GC is possible, but it is there when I click Start, because Start is called from the instance. If it wouldn't exist, it wouldn't start.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say, this self trick has saved me a *ton* of hair pulling.

I didn't think to create a reference like this. It means dynamically-created elements with on click events can call the correct instance of my class.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

i.e.

```
var name = findInstanceOf(cPoll);

function findInstanceOf(obj) {
    for (var v in window) {
        try {
            if (window[v] instanceof obj)
                return v;
        } catch(e) { }
    };
    return false;
}
```

From http://www.liam-galvin.co.uk/2010/11/24/javascript-find-instance-name-of-an-object/#read

Answer (score 0):

```
var self = this;
this.tmo = setTimeout(function(){
     self.Poll();
}, this.iInterval);
```

Comment: `this = pointerToInstanceInMemory`, therefore, `self = pointerToInstanceInMemory`

Comment: @J-P: I mean creating an alias that points to an object which is null means the alias is also null...

Comment: `this` *cannot* be `null` in JavaScript. It's impossible.

Comment: Why not ? A pointer can always be null. Obviously it is possible, and at least it definitely is in IE8

Comment: I don't see how that could be possible. Please let me know what code makes `this === null` ...

Answer (score 0):

I provided an answer for a similar question today in which I created a polling class from scratch. You may want to adopt it for yourself.  In the sake of not duplicating, here's a link a link to said question:

[Poll the Server with Ajax and Dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455900/poll-the-server-with-ajax-and-dojo/2456014#2456014) *

* Despite the title, my solution offers both "vanilla" and Dojo styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this handy little wrapper to execute a function periodically at given interval (1 sec by default):

```
function tick(func, interval) {
    return (function() {
        if(func())
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval || 1000);
    })();
}
```

The function is repeated until it returns false:

```
tick(function() {
   if(should stop) return false;
   do stuff
   return true;
});
```

If the function is a method, make a closure as shown

```
// inside your object
var me = this;
tick(function() {
   return me.doStuff();
});
```