# JavaScript: List global variables in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get the instance name of my class.

The way I do this is I loop through all global objects and compare it with the this pointer.

It works in Chrome and FF, but in IE, it doesn't. The problem seems to be the global variables don't seem to be in window.

How can I loop through the global variables in IE ?


PS: I know it only works as long as there is only one instance, and I don't want to pass the instance's name as a parameter.

```
        function myClass() 
        { 
            this.myName = function () 
            { 
                // search through the global object for a name that resolves to this object
                for (var name in this.global) 
                {
                    if (this.global[name] == this) 
                        return name 
                }
            } 
        }





        function myClass_chrome() 
        { 
            this.myName = function () 
            { 
                // search through the global object for a name that resolves to this object
                for (var name in window) 
                {
                    if (window[name] == this) 
                        return name ;
                }
            } ;
        }

// store the global object, which can be referred to as this at the top level, in a
// property on our prototype, so we can refer to it in our object's methods
myClass.prototype.global = this
//myClass_IE.prototype.global = this
 // create a global variable referring to an object
// var myVar = new myClass()
var myVar = new myClass_chrome()
//var myVar = new myClass_IE()

 alert(myVar.myName() );// returns "myVar"
```

Comment: Can you provide more context.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: Getting the instance name of a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better idea, solved:

```
        function myClass_IE() 
        { 
            this.myName = function () 
            { 
                // search through the global object for a name that resolves to this object
                for (var i = 0; i < document.scripts.length; i++)
                {
                    var src = document.scripts[i].innerHTML ;
                    //document.write('script ' + i + ' = ' + document.scripts[i].innerHTML )


                    var idents = src.replace(/\W/g, ' ').replace(/(function|if|for|while|true|false|null|typeof|var|new|try|catch|return|prototype|this)/g, '').split(' ');
                    for(var j = 0; j < idents.length; j++) 
                    {
                        //var iden = String(idents[j]).trim();
                        var iden = String(idents[j]);
                        if (window[iden] == this) 
                        {
                            // http://mcarthurgfx.com/blog/article/iterating-global-variables-in-internet-explorer
                            // http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript
                            return iden;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }





        function myClass() 
        { 
            this.myName = function () 
            { 
                // search through the global object for a name that resolves to this object
                for (var name in this.global) 
                {
                    if (this.global[name] == this) 
                        return name 
                }
            } 
        }





        function myClass_chrome() 
        { 
            this.myName = function () 
            { 
                // search through the global object for a name that resolves to this object
                for (var name in window) 
                {
                    if (window[name] == this) 
                        return name ;
                    }
            } ;
        }

// store the global object, which can be referred to as this at the top level, in a
// property on our prototype, so we can refer to it in our object's methods
myClass.prototype.global = this
//myClass_IE.prototype.global = this
// create a global variable referring to an object
// var myVar = new myClass()
//var myVar = new myClass_chrome()
var myVar = new myClass_IE()

alert(myVar.myName() );// returns "myVar"
```

Answer (score 2):

In IE, it global variables aren't enumerable unless you explicitly define them as properties of the window object.

```
var noEnum = true;       // won't show up in a for...in loop
window.willEnum = true;  // will show up in a for...in loop
```

Clearly, you found your own solution but it will work for inlined scripts only - although this could be extended to external scripts using ajax to fetch the contents from the cache (or from the server if they're not cached).