# [javascript]Where are all functions in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

If i want to take all functions and variables declared in my program in firefox i just iterate 'window' object. For example if i have var a=function() {}; i can use a(); or window.a(); in firefox, but not in IE. I have function iterating window object and writing all function names declared in program like that:

```
for (smthng in window) {
    document.write(smthng);
}
```

works in FF, in IE there are some stuff but nothing i declare before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known JScript bug.

In IE, global variables aren't *enumerable* unless you explicitly define them as properties of the window object.

```
var a = function () {};     // It won't be enumerated in a `for...in` loop
window.b = function () {};  // It will be enumerated in a `for...in` loop
```

The above two ways are really similar, the only difference is that `a` is declared with the `var` statement, and this make it non-deletable, while `b` can be "`deleted`".

```
delete window.a; // false
delete window.b; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround: [JavaScript: List global variables in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462199/javascript-list-global-variables-in-ie)