# Get name of instance of a class within the class

Tags: javascript, oop

Here is what I want:

```
var Validator = function () {
   this.do = function () {
      alert(INTANCENAME); /// SHOULD BE 'FOO'
   }
}
var FOO = new Validator().do();
```

Is it possibe to implement in Javascript?

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the object of having objects in the first place?

Comment: I don't think `FOO` is the name of the instance rather the name of the variable that the instance is currently stored.

Comment: But still, it's hard to see the point of doing so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get class object's name as a string in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789675/how-to-get-class-objects-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truth is there is no point of doing that, the only way I can hardly think is to loop all `window` or scope objects and check some kind of equality with the current object, something like

```
this.do = function () {
    for(var key in window) {
        if(this === window[key]) {
           alert(key);
        }
    }
};
```

In order to work call it after you assign it.

```
var FOO = new Validator();
FOO.do();
```

Another issue that can come up is that an instance (a reference) can be stored in various variables so maybe will not get what you expect.

Comment: this works, there is an alternative but similar solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462199/javascript-list-global-variables-in-ie/2462341#2462341

Answer (score 2):

The literal answer to your question would be:

1. Use `(new Error()).stack` to get information on the line and the function where the `do()` method was called.
2. Use JS parser (e.g. Esprima) to find out what variable it was called on (if any, the method itself might be assigned to a variable).

I do not recommend doing this though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to directly do what you're asking for here. Objects themselves are not in any defined by their matching variable name - in fact it's possible to have objects that exist that are not directly assigned to a variable, and multiple variables assigned to the same object.

The javascript interpreter uses our variable names as identifiers to help with the code execution, but once it's running the variable name makes no difference to the running javascript program, as it's probably been reduced to a memory reference by the time it's executing, completely separated from the original code that you wrote.

Edit: Answer by yannis does kind of simulate this, but it relies on working with variables available in a specific scope - what I ment was that there's no direct way to do this from within the object itself as per your example in the question.